# Nested ObservedObject in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making app in SwiftUI. I have following model:

```
struct Transaction {
    var title: String
    var category: TransactionCategory
    var value: Double
    var date: Date
    let id = UUID()
}
```

```
class Account: ObservableObject {
    
    var name: String = ""
    var currency: String = ""
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var balance: Double = 0
    @Published var trancactions: [Transaction] = []
}
```

and this works I expected. I can add new transaction and list all transactions in SwiftUI List view.

Now I'd like to add `AccountManager` to keep many account:

```
class AccountManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var accounts: [Account] = []
}
```

but when I try for example add and display all transaction from choosen account, it doesn't refresh.

```
@ObservedObject private var manager =  AccountManager()

...

List(manager.accounts[0].trancactions, id: \.id) { t in
     TransactionRow(transaction: t)
}
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to display all transactions from all accounts or filter them. Is my idea fixable or maybe I need to try a different approach?

Comment: FIrst off I recommend using `@StateObject` over `@ObservableObject`. But beyond that. A way I have solved this is by putting a view model in the TransactionRow as well. So basically each TransactionRow would also have its own `@StateObject`.

Comment: Account needs to be observed on its own. You can observe the individual items in the array like this

Comment: @aeskreis what you would keep in `@StateObject` in TransactionRow?

Comment: The TransactionRow `@StateObject` would be the `Account`